# Save created .txt file via Savefiledialog in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, methods

I have a method that returns a .txt file. As it is, it saves it in the debug folder of my project. I however aim to create a button that saves the .txt file to wherever the user wants it to be saved.

This is the method that creates the .txt file

```cs
public static void Createtxtfile(string file)
{
    string textPath = @"" + file + ".xml";
    int capacity = 1000000;
    int maxCapacity = 999999999;
    StringBuilder textfile = new StringBuilder(capacity, maxCapacity);
    InitializeProject(File.ReadAllText(textPath), textfile);
    CreateATextFile(textfile.ToString(), "textfile-" + file + ".txt");
}
```

This works great so far. CreateATextFile is a function that reads everything from textfile and dumps it into the debug folder, like so.

```cs
public static void CreateATextFile(object data, string fileName)
{
    var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        writer.Write(data);
        writer.Close();
    }
}
```

I would like to code a button that saves the textfile to a user specified location, but cannot figure out what would be the best course of action.

```cs
public void icon_dl_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
    if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog.FileName, textfile.ToString());
}
```

I understand why the textfile is not recognized in the button click method, as it is created in the Createtxtfile method.
Is there a way to allow access to the same file despite the varying methods? I'm not looking to call upon the Createtxtfile method again when pressing the download button

EDIT :

The InitializeProject method initializes the stringbuilder. This is done out of functions that are being received via the .dll file attached

```cs
[DllImport("Textfunctions.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern void InitializeProject(
        string file,
        StringBuilder textfile,);
```

Comment: you can set a variable in class scope to hold the path for your debug.txt which you can refer to in any function in your class

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your description correctly, your problem is in icon_dl_Click(), the variable textfile is unknown?

If so, you can make the textfile a variable known to both Createtxtfile() as well as icon_dl_Click(). Which means in Createtxtfile(), instead of saying

```
StringBuilder textfile = new StringBuilder(capacity, maxCapacity);
```

you should declare StringBuilder textfile outside of it, such as a class member variable. So in Createtxtfile() you say

```
this.textfile = new StringBuilder(capacity, maxCapacity);
```

and in icon_dl_Click() you say

```
File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog.FileName, this.textfile.ToString());
```

Assuming these two methods are in the same class. Of course, then you don't really need "this.", just "textfile".

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Sort of. I understand your reasoning but I am dependend on initializing the stringbuilder in an external method due to dll functions. I've edited my answer to reflect this

Comment: my approach would be to give a path in every method, so you are independend from you dll and can manage all file actions in the application itself